# How to add 4 buttons to rectangle/Circle shape

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm begainer in SL devlopment, need help!

I want to add 4 buttons to a rectangle & want to catch mouse click events from these buttons.

Initially i directly tried to add buttons to rectangle shape but i coudn;t (as rectangle shape is not container)

then I tried making that rectangle as button control (using make control thru MS Blend) but u can't catch as

child buttons click event are not bubbled up to the parent.

So please tell what container i shud use

My Req is simple Circular/rectangle  containing 4 buttons &  added child buttons these shud be able to fire all mouse events

Answer (score 0):

A grid can contain all 4 buttons *and* a rectangle and will not stop you catching the click events.

If you want a user control you need to expose the 4 click events via new event properties (and not via event bubbling). You catch the 4 separate click events and pass them back via a single  custom event if you like.